# Regain root access on EC2 if group deleted

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I was trying to add ec2-user to the apache group but for some reason, instead of adding apache to its groups, it became the only group. Now I don't have sudo access on that user account. Is there any way to gain access to the root account and fix that or does Amazon AWS have a way to restore those permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS cannot access the operating system within your instance. This is by design.

There is a way to fix it, but it's not all that easy. You would detach your root volume. Then attach it to a new instance. Fix your configuration to restore access, and move the volume back to the original instance.

Depending how much work you have done on it, it may be just as easy to start over.